# Swift namespace in objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, namespaces

There is a problem with my old source code. I'm going to add new swift files to the project done with objective-c. Everything works fine except compiler asks to add Swift namespace to all types like String, Array, Void etc in swift files.
So I have to write

```
let foo: Swift.String
```

instead of simply String.
Not a big deal but why?